# tikzDevice in Lyx

Tags: r, knitr, lyx

Would like to use the tikzDevice in conjunction with knitr, but am unable to get Yihui's Code Externalization (Stat546-HW4-Xie.lyx) demo working.

Rscript is in the path and Lyx 'view messages' reveals:

```
13:07:08.450: Quitting from lines 68-68 (C:/Users/awhite/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6728/lyx_tmpbuf2/Stat546-HW4-Xie.Rnw) 
13:07:08.452: Error in createLockFile(lockname) : cannot create lock file
13:07:08.454: Calls: knit ... evalWithoutInterrupts -> .Call -> dbFetch -> dbFetch -> createLockFile
13:07:08.456: Execution halted
support/Systemcall.cpp (273): Systemcall: 'Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore "C:/Program Files (x86)/LyX 2.0/Resources/scripts/lyxknitr.R" "C:/Users/awhite/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6728/lyx_tmpbuf2/""Stat546-HW4-Xie.Rnw" "C:/Users/awhite/AppData/Local/Temp/lyx_tmpdir.Hp6728/lyx_tmpbuf2/""Stat546-HW4-Xie.tex" ISO-8859-15 "C:/Users/awhite/Dropbox/Programming/LaTeX/Code_externalization/example2/"' finished with exit code 1
Error: Cannot convert file
```

I've followed the setup as per "Using Sweave with Lyx" and ensured that the R code works from within RStudio.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Lyx version: 2.0.7
R: 3.0.2
MiKTeX : 2.9

### UPDATE:

What I've just discovered is that when I copy the files (.lyx, .R, .csv) out of dropbox and run from desktop it works. Spaces in the dropbox path a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem with Google Drive.

Try shutting the Dropbox application down when you compile your file or at least disable its synchronization.

I tried it and it worked with Google Drive. Spaces in path to the file didn't affect the result.